# Trying out version control (git), am I doing it right?

Tags: git, version-control

I've never used version control before but I know it's a good practice, so I decided to try it out. I like git, so I'm using that. I have a local Ubuntu server (separate box) where I do all my local development.

So I installed gitosis (following the Ubuntu community docs) and set up all that jazz.

My IDE is Eclipse, so I installed Eclipse EGit.

I have my Apache docroot shared with Samba so on my Windows PC (where I develop) I just load my projects into Eclipse and save them directly to the docroot (so like \webserver\www\projectname is my network share).

So my understand of Git is that I should create my repositories in /srv/gitosis/repositories. But when using EGit, it just saves the repository to /var/www/projectname/.git - is that normal? I'm a little confused as to how the whole thing should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using a network share, you're essentially operating directly on your server, so there's no need for the whole gitosis thing.

In a normal source code repository situation, one would not have a network share with their centralized server.  They would simply access it by SSH.  In that case, gitosis is a solution they might use to provide certain users read/write access to the repository.  They would push their updates to the server and pull down the updates of others.

However, in your case, you're accessing the server directories from a network share, so as far as git is concerned, it's the same as a local directory.  All you need to do is code and commit.  No pushing and pulling required.

However, operating directly on your web server's content directory is probably not what you want.  The reason is that as you make changes, switch branches, etc, you'll end up putting your web server into a bad state.  Think about it.  You've got your fully functional website on the master branch.  Then you checkout branch "my_website_2.0" which is not yet complete.  Suddenly, all the files to which your web server points are in this half-completed state.  Not good.

There are lots of solutions to this problem, some complex, some not.  For example, you could setup a shared repository on the server to which to push your master branch, and then clone it to your web content directory.  (Note this would all still be done with simple paths, because of your network share).

This page:  [Using git to manage website](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) goes into detail on how to use git and have it automatically put shared changes in your webserver content directory, without having to do the clone on the server.

I'm sure if you google around, you'll find additional solutions.

---

Here's some additional detail, given your confusion below.

Egit (and git itself) works on local repositories.  There is not a command to configure remote repositories.  You push to and pull from remote repositories, and that's about it.  You're expecting Egit to do things it doesn't do.

Here's what you need to do:

1. Create a bare repository on your server.  Since you're using a network share, that would look something like:  "git init --bare /mynetworkshare/usr/repositories/my_central_repo"
2. Clone that repository locally: git clone /mynetworkshare/usr/repositories/my_central_repo my_local_repo
3. Add your web server files to the local repo:  cp -r my_webserver_files/* my_local_repo
4. cd into the local repo:  cd my_local_repo
5. Add the files to git:  git add . (note the dot)
6. Commit:  git commit -m "Initial commit of webserver files"
7. Push the files to the central repository.  "git push origin master"

There.  You now have a copy of the files in your bare, centralized repository.  As stated earlier, now the task is to get those files from there into your web content directory.  You could do that by cloning the central repository into your web content directory, or use a more sophisticated solution, like the one I linked or others you can find via google.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you don't need to set up gitosis, Git is very flexible, I would just create a directory on the server and use your normal SSH credentials.

Second of all, GIT is distributed, which means that everyone that clones a project has the whole history, that's  why you see the .git directory. To use it with the ubuntu server you should add a remote. A basic usage with Git from the commandline would be something like this:

#### Create the project

```
user@local:~$ mkdir project
user@local:~$ cd project
user@local:~/project$ nano filename.py
```

#### Make it a git repo

```
user@local:~/project$ git init
user@local:~/project$ git add filename.py
user@local:~/project$ git commit -m "My first commit"
```

#### Create a remote

```
user@local:~/project$ ssh ubuntu-server
user@ubuntu-server:~$ mkdir project.git
user@ubuntu-server:~/project.git$ cd project.git
user@ubuntu-server:~/project.git$ git init --bare
user@ubuntu-server:~/project.git$ exit
```

#### Add the remote

```
user@local:~/project$ git remote add origin ubuntu-server:/home/username/project.git
user@local:~/project$ git push origin master
```

I did'nt comment this much but it can maybe give you an idea of the workflow and how to use it with Eclipse...

Comment: Good detail, but remember that he's trying to use git for a website.  A bare repo on his webserver won't help get the files into his web content directory.

Comment: I still don't understand how to use the repo location in Eclipse. If I go to Team>Share project>GIT, the only acceptable repository it will allow me to create is /.git in the project location. If I create a repository first and try to import it, it wants me to add source and destination refs but I have no idea what I'm supposed to use for those - nothing seems to work.

Comment: @wadesworld: Oh. That's right. But you shared a good link for that :)

Comment: @CrazeD: The thing you want to worry about is not where the repository are (it should be in project/.git) but where the remotes point to. I'm not sure thought how you add them in EGit

Comment: Well,  I was hoping to not have my webroot full of repositories. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: I think @wadesworld seem to have a good link that describes that.

Comment: Understand that Egit only deals with your local repository.  That's how git works.  There is no "configure my remote repository" command.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: @wadesworld You mean "that's how Egit works" i suppose? Because git certainly deals with remotes via the "git remote" commands. But the problem might be that I'm mixing up the terminology?

Comment: @CrazeD: Ok. I made two misstakes 1) Did'nt thought of that you using it to work on directory accessed by the webserver 2) Answered thougt I don't know Eclipse and Egit very much. So don't listen to me, listen to @wadesworld! ;)

Comment: @NiclasNilsson "git remote" commands simply configure a symbolic name for a remote repository, allowing you to push or pull from that repository.  It is possible to make changes to a remote repository directly, but that's getting into advanced territory.  For most users, and particularly for beginning users, they should make changes to remote repositories by changing their local repository and pushing the changes.